# Ember data custom arrays push and delete

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I was implementing an array for my ember data property

```
DS.JSONTransforms.array = {
  serialize: function(value) {
    return Em.isNone(value) ? [] : value ;
  },
  deserialize: function(value) {
    return Em.isNone(value) ? [] : value ;
  }
};
```

And I created this jsbin for test to add and remove items to the array http://jsbin.com/avENazE/4/edit

If I check the console

```
model.get('pages').push('hi');
console.log(model.get('pages'));
```

I can see that the new items are corectly add to the array, but are not displayed on the view.

Also the count property is not updated and this error shows on the console on save the model

```
Uncaught TypeError: You must pass a resolver function as the sole argument to the promise constructor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The make the `view` be aware of changes of the representing model data you need data binding to work properly. To get data binding to work properly you need to use the correct functions that are sensible to bindings, so in the case of operations done to an array you can't just use vanilla `push` but instead `pushObject` or the counterpart `removeObject`, the same applies for setting a new value to a property, while dot notation will work it will not update you bindings therefore `.set()` and `.get()` need to be used etc.

So that said, here your working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/avENazE/5/edit).

Hope it helps.